# Проброс порта и перенаправление трафика через iptables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, iptables, nat

Есть роутер `192.168.1.1`, на него приходит интернет.

На роутере проброшен порт `6666` на сервер с *Ubuntu* (`192.168.1.2`, интерфейс `eth0`). Там же на сервере установлен второй интерфейс `eth1`, к которому подведена отдельная локалка (`ip` адрес сервера в этой сети `10.10.10.2`, основный шлюз - `10.10.10.1`). Через эту локалку доступен комп в 3-ей сети `192.168.100.1:6666`.

Задача: настроить `iptables ubuntu` так, чтобы пользователи через интернет по порту `6666` могли достучаться до `192.168.100.1`. 
Форвардинг включен.

Никак не могу понять, как правильно прописать следующую логику (если она вообще правильная):

1. Перенаправить пакеты с одного интерфейса `eth0` на другой `eth1`, если опрашивают `192.168.1.2:6666`.
2. Перенаправить пакеты с `10.10.10.2` `eth1` на ip-адрес доступный через эту локалку  `192.168.100.1:6666`.

Answer (score 2):

(На сервере `ubuntu`) Указываем маршрут до `192.168.100.1`:

```sh
ip route add 192.168.100.1 via 10.10.10.1
```

Меняем адресата в пакетах на `192.168.100.1`:

```sh
iptables --table nat --insert PREROUTING \
    --proto tcp --dport 6666 --jump DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.1:6666
iptables --table nat --insert PREROUTING \
    --proto udp --dport 6666 --jump DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.1:6666
```

Если роутер `192.168.0.1` не имеет маскарад, то:

```sh
iptables --table nat --insert POSTROUTING --jump MASQUERADE
```

Должно, по идее, заработать.